# Is it possible to make a discord application + bot that gives you a certain role after you connect?

Tags: oauth-2.0, discord, discord.js, discord.net

What I am attempting to do is make a verification website for my Discord server that prompts you to do a captcha, after that redirects you to a Discord application oauth2 page then after you connect my bot inside the server will automatically give you a role "Verified".
I just wanted to know if it was possible and if so how?
[Captcha before redirect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uH4pF.png)

[OAuth2 page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dfIdb.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We don't write your code for you. Please show a [mcve] and see [ask] more information

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible.

You should use `express` or `http` as a backend, and when the user joins, DM them a URL to the captcha. You could link the username to the URL, and once they complete the captcha, you should redirect them to the oauth2 page. Once those 2 requirements are complete, make the bot assign them a role.